# How to Embed Contact Form 7 Short in HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I need to embed the Contact Form 7 shortcode in HTML. I've tried the following, but it's not rendering for some reason:

```
<div class="services-contact">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1442" title="Service 1"]'); ?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I do the inspect, the code gets commented out in HTML.

Comment: Make sure you write that in a .php file, can you send a link to your website?

Comment: Might be silly but...Have you checked if a form with the id "1442" exists?

Comment: Of course, I've made it.. :)

Comment: Why do you 'do the inspect' ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code :

```
<?php $contact='[contact-form-7 id="1442" title="Service 1 "]'?>
<?php echo do_shortcode($contact);?>
```

Comment: When I do the inspect, the code gets commented out in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to insert an URL and it worked:

<a href="https://[contact-form-7 id="10742" title="Register"]">

Hope it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

your method is correct but you can also try this `apply_filters('the_content','[contact-form-7 id="1442" title="Service 1"]')`
also please make sure there is a contact form 7 exists with the id, '1442'

Comment: Give me full example please. Thanks.

Comment: When I do the inspect, the code gets commented out in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed it into a HTML file, you need to have a .PHP file connected to a server with wordpress installed on it so the php functions and wordpress functions could work.

Comment: It is wrapped in the PHP file mate. It's the wordpress installation.

Comment: can you send your entire page code in a pastebin or a url to the page?

Comment: It's a part of much bigger application, unfortunately no. But all I'm trying to do it embed the contact form, nothing else.

Comment: When I do the inspect, the code gets commented out in HTML.

Comment: Without more information or more code from your page it's not possible to get a normal answer as the code you insert is correct.